# Image Background issue in canvas

Tags: java, android

I am trying to generate image from my RelativeLayout and want share it. I have managed to generate image and share but its drawing black background behind my image, I have tried color to transparent but still it have black background. My code looking like this

```
findViewById(R.id.actionImage).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //constant.ad_count = constant.ad_count + 1;
       // methods.ShowIntAds();
        Bitmap bitmap =getBitmapFromView(main);
        try {
            File file = new File(QuoteDetailsActivity.this.getExternalCacheDir(),"logicchip.png");
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
            //file.setReadable(true, false);
            final Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
            intent.setType("image/png");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share image via"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
});
```

and

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    /*Drawable bgDrawable =view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable!=null) {
        //has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }   else{
        //does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    }*/
    view.draw(canvas);
    return returnedBitmap;
}
```

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".activities.QuoteDetailsActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/quote_details_activity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/main_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/likeIcon"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/likeIcon"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:tint="@color/quote_time_icon"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_time" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblTime"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="@color/quote_time_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/lblTime"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textPageCount1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:textColor="@color/quote_time_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/lblTime"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/mybg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/quoteViewPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/admob"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </LinearLayout>


        <View
            android:id="@+id/bottomShadow"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1.5dp"
            android:background="@color/toolbar_devider" >
        </View>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/pageNavLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar"
            android:background="@drawable/title_bar"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/butPrev"
                style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_but_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_but_size"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/tool_prev"
                    android:tint="@color/toolbar_icon"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="1.5dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/toolbar_devider" />




            <RelativeLayout

                android:id="@+id/img_fav"
                style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_but_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_but_size"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_clipboard"
                    android:tint="@color/toolbar_icon" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="1.5dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/toolbar_devider" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/actionImage"
                style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true">


                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    android:id="@+id/imgImage"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_but_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_but_size"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_background"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:tint="@color/toolbar_icon" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="1.5dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/toolbar_devider" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/actionFav"
                style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true">


                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    android:id="@+id/imgFavourite"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_but_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_but_size"
                    android:src="@drawable/fav_new_ic"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:tint="@color/toolbar_icon" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="1.5dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/toolbar_devider" />

            <RelativeLayout

                android:id="@+id/butShare"
                style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_but_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_but_size"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/fab_share"
                    android:tint="@color/toolbar_icon" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="1.5dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/toolbar_devider" />

            <RelativeLayout

                android:id="@+id/butNext"
                style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_but_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_but_size"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/tool_next"
                    android:tint="@color/toolbar_icon" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Note : I want get image of view called mybg

Let me know if someone can help me fore generate full size image without black background in it. 
Thanks

Comment: what does `view.getBackground()` return? is it not `null`? if so, what are its bounds?

Comment: Hi!, Its showing null, I do not have idea about bounds.

Comment: so you dont have any background

Comment: I do not need any background.

Comment: post your `RelativeLayout` definition in xml and the bitmap you got from `getBitmapFromView` method

Comment: @pskink, I have added xml file. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189721/discussion-between-raju-bhatt-and-pskink).